# React Package.json file setupFiles for Jest not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am creating some unit tests where I need to load .js file that contains a number of global variables under window.env.

In the package.json file under the jest key, I added the configuration "setupFiles": ["/configSettings.js"]. However, when I run the test my component, the global variable that needs to be set for example, window.env.myvar, is not being set and the test fails.

I did notice in the jest output the following error:

Jest: Coverage Data for setupFiles was not found

What extra do I need to do in order to set the window.env variables? I am using jest with react-testing-library.

Comment: Try using `jest.config.js` for configuration instead: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration

Comment: Where should the jest config be located

Comment: In Project root.

Comment: Can simply copy all the variables from the config into the jest one?

Comment: I added a jest.config.js and used the module.exports and set the setupFiles to the path of the configuration file including <rootDir>. I have tried setting with and without the package.json to the jest config but I am still getting exactly the same problem